# ReactJS Ajax call returns with 200 and results but Error: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have the below code to fetch data through an API call from the back-end. If I load the link in the *** to the browser, API does return a result '["2016-03-31T00:00:00"]' when I do an AJAX call using the below code, I get status 200, and response shows like I got a correct return from the server but browser shows 'Error: Failed to fetch' error. All I am trying to do is to make an AJAX call to that url and display the result.

Error Screenshot
[image]

Code

```
 componentDidMount() {
        fetch("***")
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(
            (result) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: result.items
              });
            },
            (error) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                error
              });
            }
          )
      }

      render() {
        const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
        if (error) {
          return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
          return <div>Loading...</div>;
        } else {
          return (
            <ul>
              {items.map(item => (
                <li key={item.name}>
                  {item.name} {item.price}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          );
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using promises, the catch() block is usually used after the then() block to handle errors. That’s why it can be used for the native fetch API.

```
fetch("***")
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(
            (result) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: result.items
              });
            }).catch((error) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                error
              });
            }
          )
```